# order of infinite countable ordinal numbers

Tags: elementary-set-theory, ordinals

I'm trying to understand ordinal arithmetic.  If one had an ordered list of the some subset of countable ordinal numbers, what order would the following 6 countably infinite ordinals be in?  If the following order is not correct, what is correct order and why is that the correct order?

$$\omega\;<\; \omega^2 \;<\; 2^\omega \;<\; \omega^\omega \;<\; {^\omega}2 \;<\;{^\omega} \omega$$

I know $\epsilon_0 = {^\omega} \omega$ is the largest, but is still countable, but I'm not sure where the powers of $2$ fit in versus the powers of $\omega$.

I understand why $\omega^2$ or $\omega^n$ for any finite value of $n$ needs to be countable.  But, why does $\omega^\omega$ need to be countable?  For cardinal numbers, $2^{\aleph_0}$ is uncountably infinite.  Presumably, there would be some contradiction in mathematics if any finite ordinal arithmetic equation involving $\omega$ generated an uncountable infinity.

Comment: What does the notation ${^\omega} 2$ mean? Never saw that (and it's hard to see what to type into Google to find it...)

Comment: Also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/154985/do-omega-omega-2-aleph-0-aleph-1 and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/197863/how-to-define-countability-of-omega-omega-and-omega-1-in-set-theory and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/598224/what-is-the-cardinality-of-omega-omega and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/318827/ordinal-exponentiation-2-omega-omega

Comment: The defining sequence for $^{\omega} 2$ is
$2\;\;2^2\;\;2^{2^2}\;\;2^{2^{2^2}}\;\;2^{2^{2^{2^2}}}....$

Comment: So then in fact ${^\omega}2=\omega$.

Comment: ok, presumably that is consistent, but it seems a bit odd, that such a fast growing sequence is regarded as smaller than $\omega^2$

Comment: I don't think this should be marked as duplicate; I would like someone to verify that size ordering is apparently:
$${^\omega} 2 \qquad 2^\omega = \omega,\qquad  \omega^2,\qquad, \omega^\omega, \qquad, {^\omega} \omega$$

Comment: Sheldon, the answer to your question appears there. Moreover, if you know that $\varepsilon_0$ is the largest and it is countable, how can you *not* know that the others are countable too?

Comment: @AsafKaragila I wanted to know the order of the sizes

Comment: Size is cardinality. They are all equal, because all of the same cardinality. If you're asking about their order as ordinals, this is indeed a different question. But in that case, you should probably edit your question to clarify that.

Comment: @AsafKaragila They are definitely NOT all equal.  My question was clearly talking about ordinal arithmetic and the relative sizes or ordinal numbers

Comment: I never said they are equal. Read my comment again.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I tried rewriting to make my question clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First note that
$$
^\omega2 := \sup \{ \underbrace{2^{2^{2^\ldots}}}_{n\text{-times}} \mid n < \omega \} = \omega.
$$

> [..]but it seems a bit odd, that such a fast growing sequence is regarded as smaller than $\omega^2$.

Well, that's the thing when dealing with infinities. Sometimes our intuition fails us. While $(\underbrace{2^{2^{2^\ldots}}}_{n\text{-times}})_{n < \omega}$ could be regarded as "a fast growing sequence", each of its elements is finite and therefore $\omega$ is an upper bound. As $\omega$ certainly is the least upper bound, we get $^\omega2 = \omega$.

By an analogous argument we get that 
$$2^\omega := \sup \{2^n \mid n < \omega \} = \omega$$

So we are left with ordering $\omega, \omega^2, \omega^\omega$ and $^\omega \omega$.

We have
$$\begin{align}\omega^2 &:= \omega \cdot \omega \\
&= \sup \{ w \cdot n \mid n < \omega\} \\
&\ge \omega \cdot 2  \\
&> \omega \end{align}$$

and

$$\begin{align}\omega^\omega &= \sup \{ \omega ^n \mid n < \omega \} \\
&\ge \omega^3 \\
&= \sup \{(\omega^2) \cdot n \mid n < \omega \} \\
&\ge \omega^2 \cdot 2 \\
&> \omega^2. \end{align}$$

Finally
$$\begin{align}^\omega \omega &:= \sup \{ \underbrace{\omega^{\omega^{\omega^ \ldots}}}_{n\text{-times}} \mid n < \omega \} \\
&\ge \omega^{\omega^\omega} \\
&= \sup\{\left( \omega^\omega \right)^n \mid n < \omega \} \\
&\ge \left(\omega^\omega \right)^2 \\
&= \omega^\omega \cdot \omega^\omega \\
&= \sup \{\omega^\omega \cdot \alpha \mid \alpha < \omega^\omega \} \\
&\ge \omega^\omega \cdot 2 \\
&> \omega^\omega. \end{align}$$

Combining these calculations we get the desired order:
$$
\omega = 2^\omega = {^\omega} 2 < \omega^2 < \omega^\omega < ^\omega\omega
$$

In general, ordinal and cardinal arithmetic are very different beasts and every ordinal arithmetic expression using only ordinals $\le \omega$ is countable.

proof (sketch)

Take a countable transitive model $M$ of a large enough fracture of $ZFC$. Every ordinal expression using only ordinals $\le \omega$ can be computed correctly inside $M$ (<- this requires some work). As $M$ only contains countable ordinals (as it is transitive), the result follows.

Comment: That is a ***horrible*** notation, ${}^\omega2$.

Comment: Thanks for the proof; much to learn.