# Is tetration and quintation etc. of infinite cardinals well defined?

Tags: set-theory, tetration

I would like to know whether tetration and quintation functions are well defined for infinite cardinals, thus, for example, $$\aleph_0 \text{ [tet] } \aleph_0 =  \aleph_0 ^ {\aleph_0 ^ {\aleph_0^{\dots}}}$$ taken $\aleph_0$ times and compounded from top to bottom, to produce a higher cardinality power set upon every recursive iteration.

In an analogous manner, $$\aleph_0 \text{ [quint] }\aleph_0 = \aleph_0 \text{ [tet] } (\aleph_0  \text{ [tet] } (\aleph_0 \text{ [tet] } \dots))$$ taken recursively $\aleph_0$ times, again compounded from top to bottom.

Since as one moves to ever higher compouding operations like tetration, quintation, sextation etc. the series of new cardinals so producded would cleary increase MUCH faster than under an operation as "slow" as "mere" exponentially recursive power set taking, do we perhaps get the production of new huge cardinals that are of a different order and character than those generated by applying infinite power set operartions?  Would all of these much larger cardinals, including even $\aleph_0\, [\aleph_0\text{ compounding operation}] \,\aleph_0$, itself compounded $\aleph_0$ times etc. still be smaller than other better known large cardinals defined in some other manner?

I hope these questions are fairly easy to comprehend. They hardly go much beyond elementary set theory. Thanks for reading and let me know if you can answer any of them!

Comment: Please use 'MathJax' for equations

Comment: As far as I know there is no natural way to define an infinite tower of cardinal exponentiation.  You could define it as a limit, but that is inconsistent with how infinite products are defined as distinct from a limit of finite products.

Comment: I once asked a similar question about ordinal arithmetic; the Op might find it interesting.  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1359801/order-of-infinite-countable-ordinal-numbers

Comment: Thanks for the reference, Sheldon!  I did find it very interesting.  It reminded me of how I once mentioned the ordinal "epsilon omega" to one of my math colleagues only to hear him stammer back emotionally; "What?! Not that damn thing again!!  I was up for three days straight trying to prove to myself that it must still be countable!!"

Answer (score 4):

dot dot dots are problematic in expressions because we require all expressions to be finite in length.  A reasonable way to interpret the first part of your question is $$\aleph_0 \text{ [tet] } \aleph_0 = \sup\{\aleph_0, \aleph_0 ^ {\aleph_0},\aleph_0 ^ {\aleph_0 ^ {\aleph_0}},\dots\}$$  This is less than or equal to the first strong inaccessible (assuming it exists).  A standard result is that if the exponent is infinite we can replace any base less than or equal to the cofinality of the exponent with $2$ so now we have 
$$\aleph_0 \text{ [tet] } \aleph_0 = \sup\{\aleph_0, 2 ^ {\aleph_0},2 ^ {2 ^ {\aleph_0}},\dots\}$$  If $\kappa$ is strongly inaccessible, we have $2^\alpha \lt \kappa$ whenever $\alpha \lt \kappa$ so the $\sup$ is at most $\kappa$.  It must be lower because this is an increasing chain of length $\aleph_0$ so the cofiniality of the $\sup$ is $\aleph_0$ and the $\sup$ is not inaccessible.

Comment: Hmm, why can't we take $\cup_n A_n$ with $A_n = 2^{A_{n-1}}$, $A_1 = \mathbb{N}$ within ZFC?  Doesn't this show the $\sup$ is an accessible cardinal?

Comment: @JairTaylor: You are right.  It has to have cofinality $\aleph_0$.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks! I was not previously familiar with [cofinality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cofinality).

Comment: @JairTaylor . You can't "reach" an inaccessible cardinal by recursion from "below" it. For one thing,  if ZF (or ZFC) is consistent then it cannot prove that an inaccessible exists.

Comment: Thanks so much to all of you who answered my questions!!  I find all of the answers helpfulful.  I will now go into the books and onto the web to try to find out just what has been written about this topic.  I am actually rather surprised that it isn't treated even in most basic set theory books and courses, since as soon as one learns that exponentiation via the power set operation creates ever larger cardinals -- which adding and multiplying do not -- it's only natural to wonder if even "faster" compoundings do something similar aa well.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet I know, I was showing that it was accessible by showing you could prove its existence in ZFC. Or did I misunderstand you?

Comment: No. You're fine.

Comment: "You can't "reach" an inaccessible cardinal by recursion from "below" it."  Yes, that is the heart of the matter in my question here.  But is this result true for any conceivable recursive process?  Is there a proof of that?

Comment: It depends on what recursive process you can conceive of.  If we define a function on the ordinals such that $\lambda$ goes to the $\lambda^{th}$ inaccessible you can reach them from below, but the function cannot be defined in ZFC.  The best primitive step available in ZFC is $\lambda \to 2^\lambda$.  Of course you can iterate that to make faster growing functions, but it still won't reach a strong inaccessible.

Comment: I just looked in on this question I posed long ago and noticed a mistake in what I wrote. If the fourth order compounding operation is called "tetration" we are clearly using Greek prefixes,  In that case, -- if anyone is interested, -- addition would be "protation," multiplication becomes "theftation,", " exponentiation, "tritation," compounded tetration, "pemptation" [or, as is more common, "pentation,"] the sixth compounding operation, "ektation," and on it goes through the greek ordinals; https://www.greekboston.com/learn-speak/ordinal-numbers-1st-20th/

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the GCH, the tetration example is tantamount to $\aleph_\omega$. If you rewrite the GCH as a tetration formula, then the pentation gets you the sequence $\aleph_\omega$, $\aleph_{\omega_\omega}$... until you get the first fixed point of the aleph function. (This is because $\aleph_0 \uparrow\uparrow \aleph_0$ gets you $\aleph_{\aleph_0}$ by replacing the index with the given factor, so then $\aleph_0 \uparrow\uparrow \aleph_{\aleph_0}$ would be $\aleph_{\aleph_{\aleph_0}}$, etc.)* But even waiving the GCH, the other posters are right, you never get higher than various $\beth$ numbers and their like, based on higher operations, without presupposing an inaccessible number (as the index of your operator) in the first place.

Major edit: even a compounded operation like $\aleph_0 \uparrow^{\aleph_0 \uparrow^{\aleph_0}\aleph_0} \aleph_0$ or an infinite such tower would give a cardinal cofinal with $\aleph_0$ and hence not an inaccessible cardinal.

Second major edit: consider $2 \uparrow^n m$, for $m$ greater than 2. This tends towards $\omega$ as $n$ increases, but without presupposing $\omega$ in place of $n$, this sequence never actually reaches it. Likewise, the smallest uncountable inaccessible must be presupposed as the index of the operation that "accesses" it. Let $\kappa$ be the smallest uncountable inaccessible. Then write $\aleph_{\alpha<\kappa} \uparrow^{\beta<\kappa} \lambda < \kappa$, when $\lambda$ is < $\kappa$ also. This expresses how without starting from $\kappa$ somewhere in one's arithmetic, one will not reach it. So one might parse "inaccessible" as "inaccessible without presupposition," hence the need for an axiom of inaccessible cardinality.

*Start with the fact that $2^{\aleph_0} = \aleph_0^{\aleph_0} = \aleph_0 \uparrow\uparrow 2$, or $\aleph_0 \uparrow\uparrow 1+1$. Then the GCH (for the $\aleph_n$ anyway) in tetration format would be $\aleph_n \uparrow\uparrow 1 + m = \aleph_{n+m}.$ For example, $2^{\aleph_2} = \aleph_2^{\aleph_2} = \aleph_2 \uparrow\uparrow 2$, so the formula gives the successor cardinal in this case again, and so on. In the infinite case, $1 + \aleph_0 = \aleph_0$, so $\aleph_0 \uparrow\uparrow \aleph_0 = \aleph_{0+\aleph_0}$. Note that $n+\aleph_0 = \aleph_0$, for all natural numbers $n$. So here $\aleph_2 \uparrow\uparrow \aleph_0$ also gives $\aleph_{\omega}$, and so on for all the $\aleph_n$. But $\aleph_0 \uparrow\uparrow \aleph_2 = \aleph_{\omega_2}$, here, etc.

Last edit: it turns out, though, that these formulae break down at the first fixed point of the aleph function, $\aleph_{\omega_{\omega_{\omega...}}}$. I will call this $\aleph_f$ or just then $f$ since $\aleph_f = f$ (this is its fixed-point character). Even in ZFC, we can establish some hypothetical bounds on powersets, like Shelah's $2^{\aleph_n} < \aleph_{\omega} \rightarrow 2^{\aleph_{\omega}} < \aleph_{\omega_4}$. We can also express failures of the GCH at various points. See Moti Gitik's "No bound for the first fixed point" for a model where the GCH holds up to $f$ but there is no bound as such on the powerset of $f$. Analogously, on our tetration model, $f \uparrow\uparrow f = f \uparrow^5 2$; I will leave to you the exercise of showing that our tetration formula gives a directly impossible result thereby. Note that here $\aleph_0 \uparrow\uparrow \aleph_f = \aleph_{\aleph_f} = \aleph_f = f$. The GCH would have $f^f = f^+$, which I *think* would be $\aleph_{f+1}$, which I *think* isn't a fixed point. But all this gives us that $f \uparrow\uparrow 2 = \aleph_{f+1}$. Now what happens then if our formula adds $f$ to itself?

Comment: Thanks, Kristian.  That strikes me as both very interesting and hardly trivial since it essentially means that no kind or number of compounded arithmetic operations will get you beyond the entire non-inaccessible indexed Beth series, so presumably there is no series ordered by end parts, "bep"s, however rapid it may be, that "breaks through" to the smallest inaccessible. That doesn't surprise me, but it is hardly trivial. Has anyone explicitly studied this "arithmetical inaccessibility" in detail. Usually they only go as far as the power set operation.

Comment: Usually the axiom of replacement covers this. Without it, $\aleph_\omega$ cannot be shown to exist in ZFC, but replacement lets us construct functional images of lower sets to get higher ones (put roughly). So infinite tetration, etc. all fall under replacement. Hint: look into descriptions of the first inaccessible that compare it to $\aleph_0$ for the analysis you're looking for.

Comment: I added some details to my answer, hopefully well-formed and informative.

Comment: Thanks for the additional information, Kristian! I noticed that someone voted your latest comment as "unhelpful." I am baffled by that since I found it VERY helpful to me as it allows me to see much more clearly and simply why no arithmetical compounding operation can ever get one to some higher level cardinals than are obtainable -- albeit more slowly -- through the power set operation. Whether some compounding operation[s] existed beyond exponentiation that also led to whole new cardinals has bugged me since I was in the U of Chicago Math Dept. 45 years ago!

Comment: You're welcome! Like you, my initial analysis of compounding, here, led me to wonder how large these cardinals would be relative to inaccessible, measurable, etc. cardinals. It wasn't until I learned about cofinality that my wonder was answered.

Comment: I have added one more section to my reply to illustrate the difficulty in defining the powerset operation and its compounded iterates, at least after a certain level of infinity is reached.

Comment: Thanks again, Kristian!  The part about how power set recursion taking breaks down at the first fixed point is especially interesting to me.  It would also seem, as least ostensibly, to invalidate, or at least require a modification to the old argument one often still hears that "there can't be any largest set, because then one could just take its power set and that would be bigger still." That must still be true in some sense, I would think, for it's hard to see how one could actually produce a bijection between f and 2^f, at least once f is specified as a set cardinal.

Comment: It also struck me as I was reading through this question and the answers once again now that I know more set theory than when I first posed it, that the analogy with the finite cardinals and U+2315

Comment: It also struck me as I was reading through this question and the answers once again now that I know more set theory than when I first posed it, that the analogy with the finite cardinals, n, their Power Sets, 2^n, and ℵ0 seems to give one a good "hint" that since no rapidity of recursive compounding operations, say 2↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑ ..... n, taken n times, can ever get you to anything more than some humongously huge, but still finite, cardinal << than the strong limit cardinal ℵ0, so too taking 2↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑ ..... ℵ0, n times -- or ℵ0 times? -- will never get you to the inaccessible strong limit card ℵω.

Comment: As I read through your comments again now, Kristian, it strikes me that it should have been obvious to me that one can't get out of the "cage" containing all such attempts to get beyond Beth-omega, assuming GCH, simply by remembering why one can't get to omega [I apologize for not using the standard character set here.] from n, or 2^n, or n tet 2, or any other such recursive "compoundings" of finite numbers however complex or rapid they may  be. Which reminds me again of my belief that the main problem with set theory is the difficulty of finding the point where the finite goes infinite.